# SSISDeploy command exception: Failed to load the ispac file

Tags: command-line, ssis

I'm trying to run the [DevOps SSISDeploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-standalone?view=sql-server-ver15#ssisdeployexe) command:

```
SSISDeploy.exe -s:"C:\git\test\Integration Services\bin\Development\Integration Services.ispac" -d:catalog;/SSISDB/TEST/DEVOPS;"TEST03,123" -at:win
```

But I'm getting this exception:

> Failed to load the ispac file 'C:\git\test\Integration Services\bin\Development\Integration Services.ispac': Specified part does not exist in the package.

Any idea what is wrong? I was able to the same using `ISDeploymentWizard.exe`

Comment: Duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/292340/61300

Comment: I was hoping to get answer from one of those :) I guess stackoverflow has much more exposure than dba.stackexchange.

Comment: try rebuilding the package as the error implies some corruption in the ispac content

Comment: regarding cross-posting: I've been annoyed in the past by contributing to a question on site X when there is much better answers/discussions already on site Y. I try to link crossposts when I notice them so potential answerers can check if their ideas have already been offered.

Comment: I've not used SSISDeploy but your example appears to align with the documentation. I can't imagine that the tool would not respect the double quotes which would be required due to the space in the project/ispac name. although you could try copy/rename the ispac to `C:\git\test.ispac` to verify. Otherwise, the bit that sticks out at me is this part of the error message `Specified part does not exist in the package` "Part" in an SSIS package would make me think of the Package Parts - are there any in the project you're attempting to deploy?

Comment: @billinkc. I agree with you. For now I've sent mail to their support: `ssistoolsfeedbacks@microsoft.com` . They were suspecting there was a mismatch between the package/project CM name in the dtproj with the real file name, However I checked and the names are identical. I will update with their response once I'll get it.

Comment: BTW, I was able to find only one similar case for it (and also involve file names): https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73481/230708 . I'm trying also to follow this suggestion: https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/59426704.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official answer form Microsoft support:

> Without a repro project, we cannot investigate it further. But a good
> news is that we will release a new version in the near future (1-2
> weeks), which contains the fix for the mismatch issue.

A new version was released `0.1.3`, which suppose to fix this issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-standalone?view=sql-server-ver15#version-013-preview